# Refreshing cache without impacting latency to access the cache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I have a cache refresh logic and want to make sure that it's thread-safe and correct way to do it.

```
public class Test {

    Set<Integer> cache = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

    public boolean contain(int num) {
        return cache.contains(num);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        cache.clear();
        cache.addAll(getNums());
    }
}
```

So I have a background thread refreshing cache - periodically call `refresh`. And multiple threads are calling `contain` at the same time. I was trying to avoid having `synchronized` in the methods signature because `refresh` could take some time (imagine that `getNum` makes network calls and parsing huge data) then `contain` would be blocked.

I think this code is not good enough because if `contain` called in between `clear` and `addAll` then `contain` always returns false.

What is the best way to achieve cache refreshing without impacting significant latency to `contain` call?

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be to use functional programming paradigm whereby you have immutable state (in this case a `Set`), instead of adding and removing elements to that set you create an entirely new `Set` every time you want to add or remove elements. This is in Java9.

It can be a bit awkward or infeasible however to achieve this method for legacy code. So instead what you could do is have 2 `Sets` 1 which has the get method on it which is volatile, and then this is assigned a new instance in the `refresh` method.

```
public class Test {

    volatile Set<Integer> cache = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean contain(int num) {
        return cache.contains(num);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        Set<Integer> privateCache = new HashSet<>();
        privateCache.addAll(getNums());
        cache = privateCache;
    }
}
```

**Edit** We don't want or need a `ConcurrentHashSet`, that is if you want to add and remove elements to a collection at the same time, which in my opinion is a pretty useless thing to do. But you want to switch the old `Set` with a new one, which is why you just need a volatile variable to make sure you can't read and edit the cache at the same time.

But as I mentioned in my answer at the start is that if you never modify collections, but instead make new ones each time you want to update a collection (note that this is a very cheap operation as internally the old set  is reused in the operation). This way you never need to worry about concurrency, as there is no shared state between threads.

Comment: Or `cache = new HashSet<>(getNums());`

Comment: "This is actually coming to the Java standard library in Java9" - Java 9 was released over 5 months ago.  What are your referring to, `Set#of`?

Comment: thanks for comments. what will happen if `cache = privateCache` and `cache.contains(num)` executed at the same time? Also volatile is also needed? and don't need ConcurrentHashSet?

Comment: the memory won't be freed until the GC is run, which might be undesirable if the cache is too big.

Comment: cache size won't be big

Comment: makes me wonder why you need a cache then or if it's really working as you expect... especially since it's small and when getNums changes you would have to refresh the whole thing anyway

Answer (score 0):

How would you make sure your cache doesn't contain invalid entries when calling contains?? Furthermore, you'd need to call refresh every time getNums() changes, which is pretty inefficient. It would be best if you make sure you control your changes to getNums() and then update cache accordingly. The cache might look like:

```
public class MyCache {

    final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Boolean> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //it's a ConcurrentHashMap to be able to use putIfAbsent 

    public boolean contains(Integer num) {
        return cache.contains(num);
    }

    public void add(Integer nums) {
      cache.putIfAbsent(num, true);
    }

    public clear(){
       cache.clear();
    }

    public remove(Integer num) {
       cache.remove(num);
    }

}
```

Comment: `volatile final`? like: keep everybody updated to the fact that I won't ever change

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten to remove "volatile"

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

As @schmosel made me realize, mine was a wasted effort: it is in fact enough to initialize a complete new `HashSet<>` with your values in the `refresh` method. Assuming of course that the cache is marked with `volatile`. In short @Snickers3192's answer, points out what you seek.

---

**Old answer**

You can also use a slightly different system.

Keep two `Set<Integer>`, one of which will always be empty. When you refresh the `cache`, you can asynchronously re-initialize the second one and then just switch the pointers. Other threads accessing the cache won't see any particular overhead in this.

From an external point of view, they will always be accessing the same `cache`.

```
private volatile int currentCache; // 0 or 1

private final Set<Integer> caches[] = new HashSet[2]; // use two caches; either one will always be empty, so not much memory consumed

private volatile Set<Integer> cachePointer = null; // just a pointer to the current cache, must be volatile

// initialize
{
    this.caches[0] = new HashSet<>(0);
    this.caches[1] = new HashSet<>(0);

    this.currentCache = 0;

    this.cachePointer = caches[this.currentCache]; // point to cache one from the beginning
}
```

Your refresh method may look like this:

```
public void refresh() {

    // store current cache pointer
    final int previousCache = this.currentCache;
    final int nextCache = getNextPointer();

    // you can easily compute it asynchronously
    // in the meantime, external threads will still access the normal cache
    CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
        // fill the unused cache
        caches[nextCache].addAll(getNums());
        // then switch the pointer to the just-filled cache
        // from this point on, threads are accessing the new cache
        switchCachePointer();
        // empty the other cache still on the async thread
        caches[previousCache].clear();
    });
}
```

where the utility methods are:

```
public boolean contains(final int num) {
    return this.cachePointer.contains(num);
}

private int getNextPointer() {
    return ( this.currentCache + 1 ) % this.caches.length;
}

private void switchCachePointer() {
    // make cachePointer point to a new cache
    this.currentCache = this.getNextPointer();
    this.cachePointer = caches[this.currentCache];

}
```

Comment: What's the point of all this boilerplate? Why not simply create a new reference?

Comment: @shmosel OP is worried that `(imagine that getNum makes network calls and parsing huge data)`. Then `cache.addAll(...)` would take a long time. That's why all this boilerplate

Comment: Who cares how long it takes? How is an async pointer switcher any improvement over `cache = new HashSet<>(getNums());`?

Comment: @shmosel you are right `cache = new HashSet<>(getNums());` is enough for the job. I was focusing too much on running the expensive computation asynchronously and keeping consistent data available in the meantime